# Forcing subfigure caption to right-middle of figure

Tags: graphics, floats

I want to plot say two figures with their respective sub captions on right-middle side of the figure. Any help?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[image: MWE]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\def\LW{\dimexpr.25\linewidth-.5em}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\parbox{\LW}{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}}\hfill%
\parbox{\LW}{\subcaption{This is the A example image}}\hfill%
\parbox{\LW}{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}}\hfill%
\parbox{\LW}{\subcaption{The B example image.}}
\caption{Example figures A \& B from the \texttt{mwe} package. Use a full
width caption here, because a centered-little caption with side 
subcaptions look awful.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1. A minor suggestion: since the subcaptions are narrow, it would be better to locally use something like  `\captionsetup[subfigure]{justification=raggedright}` to prevent ugly spacing issues in the subcaptions (which you will see if you change the second subcation to, for example, `\subcaption{Another ugly image.}`)

Comment: @GonzaloMedina I agree, I do not pay attention to this or hyphenation issues for the example. However in a real work my preference would be a wider side caption, a small sans serif and use `microtype` rather that allow a ragged margin.

Comment: Thanks @Fran: The solution really works for me. However i was getting package conflicts with subcaption. But without subcaption it also works.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}

\includegraphics[width=.2\textwidth,valign=m]{example-image-a}
\begin{minipage}{.2\textwidth}
\caption{an image}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\includegraphics[width=.2\textwidth,valign=m]{example-image-b}
\begin{minipage}{.2\textwidth}
\caption{another image}
\end{minipage}


\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks @David : The solution works but the sub-cations aligns at bottom-right of figure. I want them in middle. Anyway solution was simple and interesting.

Comment: @VinayakAbrol no. Look at the image I posted, they are middle aligned.

Answer (score 0):

```
A simple modification to Frank's answer

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\def\LW{\dimexpr.9\linewidth-.5em}
\def\LWW{\dimexpr.1\linewidth-.5em}
\begin{figure}
\graphicspath{ {./images/} }
\centering 
\parbox{\LW}{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=3cm]  {1.eps}}
\parbox{\LWW}{(a)}\\
\parbox{\LW}{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=3cm]{2.eps}}
\parbox{\LWW}{(b)}\\
\parbox{\LW}{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=3cm]{mdct_d1.eps}}
\parbox{\LWW}{(c)}
\caption{Example figures A \& B from the package.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```