# Text and Image side by side

Tags: graphics

[image]
I'm trying to insert these images and those side captions { a) bla bla, b) bla bla} separately, but without sucess until now. Sometimes there's three or four images following this model in my work. I tried a few codes and did not look quite as this. Am I missing someghing quite simple, I suppose?

I'm trying this, but there's no vertical alignment (between the figure the respective caption)

```
\begin{figure}[!htb]
    \centering
    \caption{Image Title}
    \begin{tabular}{cc}
     a) bla bla bla & \includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{image1} \\
    b) bla bla bla & \includegraphics[width=0.33\textwidth]{image2}
    \end{tabular}
    \label{Image Label}
\end{figure}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a proposal based on [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/225804/121799).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\captionsetup{position=top}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{justification=raggedleft}
% from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/225804/121799
\def\LW{\dimexpr.25\linewidth}
\def\RW{\dimexpr.75\linewidth-.5em}
\newcommand{\picA}{\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily]
\draw[thick] (0,-0.2) -- (6,-0.2);
\foreach \X[count=\Z,evaluate=\Z as \Y using int(\Z+3)] in {0,3,6}
{
 \draw[thick,-latex] (\X,0.2) -- ++(0,0.8) node[above]{d$_\Y$};
 \draw[thick,-latex] ({\X+0.5},0) arc(0:180:0.5) node[left]{d$_\Z$};
 \fill (\X,-0.2) circle (1pt);
 \fill[pattern=north east lines,thick] ({\X-0.7},-0.7) rectangle
 ({\X+0.7},-1.2);
 \draw[thick] ({\X-0.7},-0.7) -- ({\X+0.7},-0.7) node[above,anchor=south east] {\Z};
 \draw[thick] ({\X-0.3},-0.7) -- (\X,-0.2) -- ({\X+0.3},-0.7);
 \path (current bounding box.south) -- ++(0,-0.1);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\newcommand{\picB}{\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily]
\draw[thick] (0,-0.2) -- (6,-0.2);
\foreach \X[count=\Z,evaluate=\Z as \Y using int(\Z+3)] in {0,3,6}
{
 \draw[thick,-latex] (\X,-2) node[above right]{f$_\Y$} -- ++(0,0.8);
 \draw[thick,-latex] ({\X+0.5},0) arc(0:180:0.5) node[left]{f$_\Z$};
 \fill (\X,-0.2) circle (1pt);
 \fill[pattern=north east lines,thick] ({\X-0.7},-0.7) rectangle
 ({\X+0.7},-1.2);
 \draw[thick] ({\X-0.7},-0.7) -- ({\X+0.7},-0.7) node[above,anchor=south east] {\Z};
 \draw[thick] ({\X-0.3},-0.7) -- (\X,-0.2) -- ({\X+0.3},-0.7);
 \path (current bounding box.south) -- ++(0,-0.1);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\parbox[b]{\LW}{\subcaption{This is the A example image}}
\parbox{\RW}{\picA}%
\\%
\parbox[b]{\LW}{\subcaption{The B example image.}}\hfill
\parbox{\RW}{\picB}%
\\%
\parbox[b]{\LW}{\subcaption{This is the A example image}}
\parbox{\RW}{\picA}%
\\%
\parbox[b]{\LW}{\subcaption{The B example image.}}\hfill
\parbox{\RW}{\picB}%
\\%
\parbox[b]{\LW}{\subcaption{This is the A example image}}
\parbox{\RW}{\picA}%
\\%
\parbox[b]{\LW}{\subcaption{The B example image.}}\hfill
\parbox{\RW}{\picB}%
\end{tabular}
\caption{Some subfigures with captions on the left.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can I ask how did you draw this using Tikz :D?  There's a plataform that converts your drawing to tex commands?

Much appreciated!

Comment: @LucasPaiva This platform is called computer and marmot claws ;-)

Comment: haha fair enough!